# Lambda expression to access a property of an object that is property of another object in c#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have this two classes:

```
public class Contratos
{
//...
    public int EntidadeFinanceiraId { get; set; }
   [Column("Nome")]
    public EntidadesFinanceiras entidadeFinanceira { get; set; }
//...
}

public class EntidadesFinanceiras
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
//...
}
```

and want to dinamically filter a List of Contratos based on Contratos.entidadeFinanceira.Nome. This is part of a Method that filters the list based on a property selected by the user.

```
    public IQueryable<Models.Contratos> applyLambdaFilter(string val, string col, string oper, IQueryable<Models.Contratos> contratosList)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            string typeName;
            string columnName;
            Type propType;
            string[] propName = col.Split(new[] { '.' });
            if (propName.Count() > 1)
            {
                typeName = "GAcordos.Models." + propName[0]; //entidadeFinanceira
                columnName = propName[1]; //Nome
                propType = Type.GetType("GAcordos.Models.Contratos").GetProperty(propName[0]).PropertyType.GetProperty(columnName).PropertyType; //String
            }
            else
            {
                typeName = "GAcordos.Models.Contratos";
                columnName = propName[0]; //Other Contratos property
                propType = Type.GetType(typeName).GetProperty(columnName).PropertyType;
            }
            if (propType != null)
            {
                var fixedItem = Comparators.getFixedItemWithType(val, propType);
                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(GAcordos.Models.Contratos), "x");
                var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, col.ToString()), fixedItem, false, Type.GetType("GAcordos.Helpers.Comparators").GetMethod(oper, new Type[] { propType, propType }));
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<GAcordos.Models.Contratos, bool>>(body, param);
                contratosList = contratosList.Where(lambda.Compile()).AsQueryable();
            }
        }
        return contratosList;
    }
```

When the Method executes it throws an exception  **'entidadeFinanceira.Nome' is not a member of type 'GAcordos.Models.Contratos'** on the line

```
var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, col.ToString()), fixedItem, false, Type.GetType("GAcordos.Helpers.Comparators").GetMethod(oper, new Type[] { propType, propType }));
```

But if I write the expression directly:

```
contratosList = contratosList.Where(x => x.entidadeFinanceira.Nome == val);
```

it works fine.

So, how can I build the lambda expression x => x.property.property == constVal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, you need two uses of `PropertyOrField`.

Constructed manually, `x => x.Foo.Bar == constVal` is:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjectType), "x");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectType, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(
           Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Foo"), "Bar"
        ), Expression.Constant(constVal, constValType)
    ), param);
```

(note that it is important to include `constValType` in case `constVal` is `null`; this avoids a lot of unexpected problems)

Comment: (note I'm glossing over the difference between a *captured* `constVal` and an explicit *constant*... but: meh)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that when calling

```
Expression.PropertyOrField(param, col.ToString())
```

the variable `col` contains "entidadeFinanceira.Nome". You may reuse all the splitting of `col` you did above and do something like:

```
Expression property = param;
foreach(var pName in propName) { 
    property = Expression.PropertyOrField(property, pName);
}
```

Now the expression `property` should be correct and you can use it to build the `body` expression:

```
var body = Expression.Equal(
    property, 
    fixedItem, 
    false, 
    Type
        .GetType("GAcordos.Helpers.Comparators")
        .GetMethod(oper, new Type[] { propType, propType })
    );
```